# Updating a list order with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1: <button id="down_1">Down</button></li>
    <li>Item 2: <button id="down_2">Down</button><button id="up_2">Up</button></li>
    <li>Item 3: <button id="down_3">Down</button><button id="up_3">Up</button></li>
    <li>Item 4: <button id="down_4">Down</button><button id="up_4">Up</button></li>
    <li>Item 5:                                  <button id="up_5">Up</button></li>
</ul>
```

and want to use jQuery, for updating list order.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[id^="down_"]').each(function() {
            var id = this.id;
            $('#' + id).click(function() {
                ///A code to change this <li>..</li> with the next one??
            });
        });
        $('[id^="up_"]').each(function() {
            var id = this.id;
            $('#' + id).click(function() {
                ///A code to change this <li>..</li> with the previous one??
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

How to write JavaScript/jQuery code for changing order? E.g if i press button with id="down_3", then result is:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1: <button id="down_1">Down</button></li>
    <li>Item 2: <button id="down_2">Down</button><button id="up_2">Up</button></li>
    <li>Item 4: <button id="down_4">Down</button><button id="up_4">Up</button></li>
    <li>Item 3: <button id="down_3">Down</button><button id="up_3">Up</button></li>
    <li>Item 5:                                  <button id="up_5">Up</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You do realize there's a reason why the site doesn't let the question to start with "Hi"...?

Comment: Also, why do you bind the `click` event inside a loop? That's exactly what makes jQuery great, it's selector engine is already optimized for this kind of functionality.

Comment: ///A code to change this <li>..</li> with the next one?? what does this mean? please explain.

Comment: @Sangeeta I assume he wants the "up" button to move the list item up in the list and "down" button to move it down (swap with the previous or next item).

Comment: Why don't use sortable of jQueryUI? http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: "Hi" Juhana, the stackoverflow removes automatically phrases "Hello", "Hi", etc.

Comment: @user2157361 Yes, so why do you think "H_i" would be any better? It removes the phrases *because they're not allowed*.

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^="up_"]').on('click', function() {
        var li = $(this).closest('li');
        li.prev('li').before(li);
    });

    $('[id^="down_"]').on('click', function() {
        var li = $(this).closest('li');
        li.next('li').after(li);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rMW2E/)

Comment: If i move to last row how to remove down-button and add the down button to the next last? The same also the first line. Thank you.

Comment: @user2157361 - I'd solve that like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rMW2E/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can use `.on()`

```
$('[id^="down_"]').on('click',function() {  });
```

And for sorting.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('[id^="down_"],[id^="up_"]').on('click',function(){
            var row = $(this).parents("li:first");
            if ($(this).is(".up"))
            {
                row.insertBefore(row.prev());
            }
            else
            {
                row.insertAfter(row.next());
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### **[`Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/hDh3k/)**

Answer (score 0):

A slightly alternative approach to [@adeneo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15612527/82548):

```
$('li button.down, li button.up').click(
    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var that = $(this),
            li = that.closest('li'),
            direction = that.hasClass('down');
        li[direction ? 'insertAfter' : 'insertBefore'](direction ? li.next() : li.prev());
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XmwBQ/1/).

Please note that I've changed the `id`s to a shared class-name for simplicity in selecting.